# JS await not working as expected

Tags: javascript, async-await

It's my first time working with async js, and it doesn't work as expected.

Here is a simple form of the problematic code:

```js
let input = document.querySelector( '#test' );

document.querySelector( '#btn' ).addEventListener( 'click', getIP );
document.querySelector( '#btn-2' ).addEventListener( 'click', test );

async function test()
{
    let value = input.value;
    if ( !value )
    {
        await getIP();
        value = input.value;
    }
  
    alert( value );

  // do something with `value`
}

function getIP()
{
    fetch( 'https://httpbin.org/get' ).then( res => {
        return res.json();
    }).then( json => {
        input.value = json.origin
    });
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="load" />
<input type="button" id="btn-2" value="execute something" />
```

This code is suppose to let the user to load their IP into the box, and then other buttons ( which are not shown in this example ) can execute actions using this IP.

However, there is a button ( `#btn-2` ) which executes a single action using the IP.

The problem is that I wanna let the users to execute the action of `#btn-2` immediately, without clicking the `load` button.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Your `getIP()` function is not written to return a Promise. It could be made `async` too, if you wanted, and written to `await` the `fetch()` call.

Comment: @Pointy So what u r saying is that I need to return the `Promise` from `fetch()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually just need a Promise from `getIp`:

```
 function getIP() {
   return fetch( 'https://httpbin.org/get' )
     .then(res => res.json());
 }
```

Then it is as easy as:

```
  async function test(){
     input.value = input.value || await getIP();    
  }
```